# Is there a tool that can automatically power off monitor on inactivity?

Tags: lxde

I am using lxde and that, unlike gnome, has no option to power off display after certain time. The screensaver can only display black screen which is still consuming lot of energy.

Is there any tool that could after N minutes turn off the display and start it on key / mouse event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use [**XScreenSaver**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xscreensaver/).

After you install it, make the following selections:

[image]
[image]

See more details about how to install and configure in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/293014/147044).

Comment: Ok, but that is exactly that tool which I already have, which has no option to power off display according to screenshots, I don't want to start screensaver, I want to power off display (power off doesn't mean show black color, but turn it off)

Comment: @Petr You probably think that you have it, but I think that you have something else. So, please try to install it and make the selections like in the images from my answer and you will see.