# Upgrading XScreenSaver

Tags: software-installation, 14.10, screensaver, xscreensaver

I got `XScreenSaver` and removed `gnome-screensaver` by following these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/293014/364819

But now when I launch XScreenSaver I get this:

[image: VERY OLD]

So I went to the website and downloaded the `xscreensaver-5.32.tar.gz` from this page: http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/download.html

But now that I have unzipped it, I cannot find anything like an `.sh` file, or any type of executable file which I could use to install it. So that is really my question, how do I install it?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Download these files:

```
64bits
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.3.1-11_amd64.deb
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xscreensaver/xscreensaver_5.30-1+b1_amd64.deb
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xscreensaver/xscreensaver-data_5.30-1+b1_amd64.deb
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xscreensaver/xscreensaver-gl_5.30-1+b1_amd64.deb

32bits
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.3.1-11_i386.deb
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xscreensaver/xscreensaver_5.30-1+b1_i386.deb
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xscreensaver/xscreensaver-data_5.30-1+b1_i386.deb
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xscreensaver/xscreensaver-gl_5.30-1+b1_i386.deb
```

With gdebi install them in this order:

```
libjpeg62-turbo
xscreensaver
xscreensaver-data
xscreensaver-gl
```