# XScreenSaver Lock Screen

Tags: 14.10, suspend, lock-screen, screensaver

I got `XScreenSaver` and removed `gnome-screensaver` by following these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/293014/364819

And my settings are as follows:

[image: XScreenSaver Preferences]

And it is all working fine and that, but I would much more prefer it to be so that when the screensaver starts, if I then wake it up, for it to go to suspend and lock, and not just to be after a certain time of being in the screensaver.

I tried achieving this by setting the "Lock Screen After" to `0`, but this just meant that when the screensaver came on, it would just immediately lock, and then the screen would go black, and so no screensaver.

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

### Package Information:

```
xscreensaver:
  Installed: 5.26-1ubuntu3
  Candidate: 5.26-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 5.26-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past you could enable this behavior under `lxde` with various combinations of `xscreensaver-command -lock` and/or `xss-lock`, but these options apparently no longer work under `systemd`.

Assuming you are using `lightdm` (which you should be on Ubuntu), you can use `light-locker` to re-enable screenlocking on suspend/resume with `xscreensaver`:

```
sudo apt-get install light-locker
```

then reboot.

Automatic locking on resume will be re-enabled, but you will have two different lock screens.

When waking up, the screen will be locked with the `lightdm-greeter` screen.

When the `xscreensaver` starts after a period of inactivity, you will still see the normal `xscreensaver` unlock screen.