# Ubuntu 16.04 lock screen without dimming/turning off

Tags: screen, lock-screen

I'm using an HP laptop with an external screen connected through an HDMI cable, and the lid closed.

Every time I lock the screen, it dims and then cuts signal to the screen, leaving it in a blue screen that says "No Signal", and eventually it just turns off.

I want to be able to lock my screen and walk away from the computer WITHOUT having the external screen turn off.

I have gone into Settings and unchecked "Dim screen to save power" and set "Turn screen off when inactive" to "Never"

I have run `xset -dpms`

I have gone into dconf-editor and set com->canonical->unity-greeter->idle-timeout to 0

Nothing works.

No matter what I do, when I lock the screen (or it auto-locks), it dims and then turns off.

Answer (score -1):

I use xscreensaver instead of gnome-screensaver.

sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver

sudo apt-get install xscreensaver

Configure xscreensaver :

[Lock screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ2Rd.png)

Those instructions are from here :
[Configure screensaver in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292995/configure-screensaver-in-ubuntu)

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!