# Is there an alternative lock-screen available?

Tags: gnome, lightdm, lock-screen, gdm, display-manager

I'm using lockscreen that came with Ubuntu Gnome. It's called GDM. can I replace it with LightDM or lockscreen that comes with KDE , LXDE or others?

what are the names of these packages? how to install them?

---

If that's too broad then

- How can I just install LightDM without affecting my Ubuntu Gnome Installation?
- How can I uninstall it and get GDM  back if I don't like the experience?

Comment: See http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or.html . What are you wanting to do exactly ? GDM/LightDM/etc are login managers not lock screens. See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-exit.html#lock-screen and clarify what you are needing please.

Comment: @SundarLabhar - Not really a dup as the OP is not asking how to install slim and the answer you linked does not explain how to configure which login manager to use , ie "How can I uninstall it and get GDM back if I don't like the experience?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install an alternate login manager use software manager or the command line

```
sudo apt-get install kdm
```

You can try slim or lightdm, both probably lighter then kdm, or try them all.

To remove them

```
sudo apt-get purge kdm
```

or slim or lightdm

To select which one to use use sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm or edit `/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager`

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

you will get a screen where you can select which display manager (login screen) to use.

[image]

Use you up/down arrow keys to select and hit enter key.

or

```
sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/displaymanager
```

and change to the dm you wish, such as

```
DISPLAYMANAGER=”kdm”
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` has the advantage of less typing and less typographical errors.

Locking the screen when you are inactive is a different issue and is a property of the screensaver you use. By default it is gnome-screensaver but xscreensaver is probably the most popular alternate.

To configure and change screensaevers see [Configure screensaver in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292995/configure-screensaver-in-ubuntu)

Comment: As neither GNOME nor Ubuntu have a screensaver by default any more these programs don't handle the lock-screen either any more.

Comment: Good points. Without additional information the info on screensavers may or may not be relevant, not sure about the nature of the question or version of Ubuntu, so the information was included for completeness.

Comment: Perhaps you should make that more clear in your answer then. So that if they are running a more recent version they will not get confused by your screensaver suggestions.