# Use blank screensaver when on battery power

Tags: battery, 19.04, screensaver

I like the screensavers, but when on battery power the blank one makes more sense. How could I configure the system to use the blank one when on battery power and other more colourful ones when on mains?

To clarify: The options to set different timeouts for battery/mains are fine; I am looking to set different screensavers (no screen content on battery power, interesting colourful stuff when on mains power).

Comment: I am not asking about timeouts, but the screen saver content.

Comment: 0h ok.. i will remove the link.. screensaver means are you using any custom ones?

Comment: Thank you. The [X screen saver ones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292995/configure-screensaver-in-ubuntu). But I would be happy to use the blank screen gnome one when on battery.

Comment: You're using xscreensaver so this might start you toward an answer To get the battery state: `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep state`will return `discharging` if your system is running on battery. ` xscreensaver` configuration is in ~/.xscreensaver. The property you're looking for in this file is `mode`. The optional values are `one`, `blank`, and `random`. So we need to find a notification of battery state change then a little `sed` piece to modify the xscreensaver configuration when the battery state changes.