# How to use htop or other system monitor as screensaver

Tags: configuration, monitor, system, screensaver, htop

I want to make system monitor like htop as screensaver or when I block computer. Is it possible to use htop or other terminal system monitor as I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Manual page: [phospor](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man6/phosphor.6x.html)

Use xscreensaver as screensaver. See [Configure screensaver in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292995/configure-screensaver-in-ubuntu) and set it up to use phospor in the advanced tab:

```
phosphor -root -delay 50000 -scale 6 -program htop
```

- root : Draw on the root window.
- scale (int) : How  much  to  scale  the  font up: in other words, the size in real pixels of the simulated pixels. Default 6.
- delay (usecs) : The speed of the terminal: how  long  to  wait  between  drawing  each  character. Default 50000, or about 1/20th second.
- program (sh-command) : 
             The command to run to generate the text to display.  **This option may be any string
             acceptable to /bin/sh**.  The program will be run at the end of a pty or  pipe,  and
             any characters that it prints to stdout will be printed on phosphor's window.  The
             characters will be printed artificially slowly, as per the  -delay  option  above.
             If the program exits, it will be launched again after 5 seconds.

---

untested until later today; the phosphor command might need an absolute path.