# Lock Screen + Photos Slideshow?

Tags: lock-screen, photoshop, slideshow

In Windows 11, I can select to have a random slideshow of pictures in the lock screen.
I can select a folder, and it takes all pictures from there and randomnly shows then in the lock screen.
Is it possible in Ubuntu latest LTS?

Comment: I think your best bet will be to install [XScreensaver](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver) following notes like the ones here: https://askubuntu.com/a/293014/1691066