# The XScreenSaver daemon doesn't seem to be running on ":0"

Tags: 12.04, screensaver

Since in Ubuntu 12.04 there weren't integrated screen savers (btw, why?), I looked for a tutorial online and installed XScreensaver 5.15.
The problem is that it won't start the sccreen savers until I've actually opened the preferences window - then it says

> The XScreenSaver daemon doesn't seem to be running on ":0". Launch it
>   now?

If I click OK, it then works.

Is there a way to get it to run when the computer starts up? A screen saver is kindah useless if you have to tell it to start every time you turn your computer on...

Here's my XScreenSaver entry in Startup Apps:
[image]

Comment: Ubuntu uses gnome-screensaver for the Unity desktop environment, not xscreensaver (correct me if I'm wrong). If you want to run xscreensaver nevertheless, you have to put it in your autostart list (that is probably somewhere in the system menu, but I don't have any Ubuntu machine nearby, so I can't tell...). You can also edit the session .desktop file (you'll find numerous guides that suggest this, yet it affects all users, so I advice against it - and session files are probably not protected configuration, so they'll be overwritten on updates).

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128481/how-do-i-set-xscreensaver-to-autostart) may be helpful.

Comment: @Danatela I have tried the answer to the question you linked, but it still doesn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry, I gave wrong link. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers) is the manual. Did you set up an entry in _Startup Applications_?

Comment: @Danatela yes, I did set up an entry in Startup apps: `xscreensaver -nosplash`

Comment: But it still doesn't work...

Comment: Then add screenshot of your Xscreensaver entry. And give output of `ps -A | grep xscreensaver`.

Comment: what do you mean "give output of `ps -A | grep xscreensaver`"?

Comment: @Danatela sorry, not really an expert...

Comment: Run the command in terminal and copy-paste it's output here. And also run `xscreensaver -nosplash` and see what it writes to you.

Comment: was this ever resolved? I cant seem to fix it

Comment: Hi there - I had everything working up through 13.10, but now in 14.04 the startup entry is no longer working. The Output from the thing @Danatela asked for (for me) is:
" 11317 ?        00:00:00 xscreensaver"
Don't know if that helps

Comment: Still looking for an answer?

Comment: @Seth yes - I never got it to work. I'll hae another look at it, maybe I can get it to work now.

Comment: PS: also I don't believe "[...] was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers" is really true: other people have had the same issue.

Comment: try this on startup applications: `bash -c 'while true;do if ! pgrep xscreensaver;then xscreensaver -nosplash;fi; sleep 1;done'`, basically it will keep trying to run it even if it fails to, so it will kick in!