# Not all are autostart programs are autostarting [ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: 16.04, autostart, screensaver

I've tried to get Xscreensaver and my-weather-indicator to autostart, they're in the Startup Application Preferences, but they're not coming on line after I log in.

Is there a way to audit what the problem is, like a log file for the startup applications?

(When I start Xscreensaver afterward, I'll get a dialog that it isn't running as a daemon and do I want to start it?. Maybe I'm missing a command to start is a daemon?)

Comment: Does this help for XScreensaver? [XScreensaver Autostart](http://askubuntu.com/a/333788/602680)

Comment: In @OwenHines link there is a comment `sh -c "sleep 10 && xscreensaver -nosplash"` which is the first thing I would try.

Comment: What about the weather program? Should I introduce a similar delay? And I'm still not sure how to audit any error responses that the commands might be getting.